# Chronic file system corruption

Tags: windows-vista, motherboard, hardware-failure

So I've been working in the computer repair biz for 5+ years now, not much is new to me.

I've got this computer, what I thought was an open and shut scenario, the original BSOD was 0x07B. Ran the appropriate hdd, failed. Mounted the drive to my workstation (Windows 7), disk management could detect the presence of the drive, can't initialize it. Good enough, confirmed bad hard drive.

So I replace the drive (brand new), reinstall the OS, all drivers, etc. Every couple of restarts the computer hangs on the vista splash screen.... the little scroller thing... something like this:
[image: something like this:]

Eventually chkdsk will automatically run. It will find several items and fix them - EVERY TIME.

Additionally, when chkdsk completes, most of the time Vista will boot successfully. The performance is quite poor, intermittently unresponsive, like the OS is corrupt. When it doesn't load completely, it will blue screen - REGISTRY_ERROR:0x0000051, which also supports corruption. So obviously I suspect something else is failing.

- Ran memtest (both sticks and individually), all passed.
- HDD diags, all passed. PSU tests passed.
- Visually inspected all motherboard capacitors, no burst/bulging.
- Checked all motherboard ports for debris or obstructions, nada.
- I flashed the bios, no change.
- I removed/disconnected all non essential hardware, no change. (USBs,
  opticals, extra ram)
- I replaced non essential hardware with known good hardware, no
  change. (ram, opticals, cables, psu)
- I reinstalled the OS using a freshly burned disc.
- I even reseated the processor....lol.

Deduction tells me the only possible explanation left is that the motherboard is failing, but I've never seen such odd behavior from a failing motherboard.

Thoughts?

Any help is good help at this point! Thanks for your time!!

P.S. I'll be active on here for the next couple hours to provide updates!

Comment: I think you pretty much answered your own question, as you **systematically** eliminated almost every source of error. It is possible that the motherboard is to blame, which *would* explain the chkdsk runs, because the motherboard does detain some control over I/O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the motherboard:

I would of first pointed to the Ram, But if ram is not functioning properly somehow, it will usually not allow you to install windows period, which I'm sure you already know. But the fact that it did allow you to install windows shows its probably not the ram. After you start noticing weird BSOD's or glitches, or instant restarts with a new hard drive (as long as the drive was formatted during the OS install and was successful) it's gotta be that motherboard. After you `Ran memtest (both sticks and individually), all passed.` You're first instinct should of pointed to the motherboard.

I'm not sure, but have you checked on the CPU temp? make sure its with it's norm aswell. And the odds of the ram or an intel cpu being an issue these days is so ridiculously low, I pretty much rule them out right away unless I notice the cpu temp is high.

Comment: I didn't use any temp monitoring software because I would periodically touch the cpu and chipset heatsink, especially when the issues occurred, never anything above slightly warm.

Comment: goto bios and check the temp, make sure its not higher than 50 C, i'm almost positive that its not the issue and the motherboard is, but you should make a habit of doing this, to rule out its a cpu problem, etc.

Comment: 30c in bios. no fluctuation so far. That's ok, I've heard enough, I'm calling it the motherboard. Thanks everyone, you've preserved my sanity!